# yellow Warnings : Conditional cast from UITextDocumentProxy to UIKeyInput always succeeds

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7, ios9

I'm working on a keyboard, I just have installed xcode 7 beta 2
and then I am getting lots of Warnings.

Over 24 yellow errors I think it makes the keyboard crash 
on xcode 6.4 No errors and no keyboard Course

I find difficulty to resolve the errors.

**Warnings:**

> Conditional cast from UITextDocumentProxy to UIKeyInput always succeeds

```
func handleBtnPress(sender: UIButton) {
    if let kbd = self.keyboard {
        if let textDocumentProxy = kbd.textDocumentProxy as? UIKeyInput {
            textDocumentProxy.insertText(sender.titleLabel!.text!)
        }

        kbd.hideLongPress()

        if kbd.shiftState == ShiftState.Enabled {
            kbd.shiftState = ShiftState.Disabled
        }

        kbd.setCapsIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

**Warnings:**

> Conditional cast from UITouch to UITouch always succeeds

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for obj in touches {
        if let touch = obj as? UITouch {
            let view = self.touchToView[touch]

            let touchPosition = touch.locationInView(self)

            if self.bounds.contains(touchPosition) {
                self.handleControl(view, controlEvent: .TouchUpInside)
            }
            else {
                self.handleControl(view, controlEvent: .TouchCancel)
            }

            self.touchToView[touch] = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a little info: 'Yellow errors' are actually warnings :) (y) and please tell us on which lines the warnings occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These aren't errors, they are just warnings and they probably aren't the cause of your crashes however you can resolve these two examples by doing the following:

The `UITextDocumentProxy` protocol conforms to `UIKeyInput` anyway so there is no need to cast `kbd.textDocumentProxy` as `UIKeyInput`.

You will be able to do the following without any warnings:

```
func handleBtnPress(sender: UIButton) {
    if let kbd = self.keyboard {
        kbd.textDocumentProxy.insertText(sender.titleLabel!.text!)
        kbd.hideLongPress()

        if kbd.shiftState == ShiftState.Enabled {
            kbd.shiftState = ShiftState.Disabled
        }

        kbd.setCapsIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Same with `obj`, compiler already knows that it is a `UITouch` object so there is no need to cast it, you can take all the code out of the `if let touch = obj as? UITouch` statement like so:

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let view = self.touchToView[touch]

        let touchPosition = touch.locationInView(self)

        if self.bounds.contains(touchPosition) {
            self.handleControl(view, controlEvent: .TouchUpInside)
        }
        else {
            self.handleControl(view, controlEvent: .TouchCancel)
        }

        self.touchToView[touch] = nil
    }
}
```

---

Little tip: <kbd>alt</kbd> click on a variable to see what type it has been resolved as:

[image]

Comment: Can you please show me how I combine the answer you code ״textDocumentProxy״?

Comment: Much better now
Thank you very much :)

Comment: Maybe you know what is causing the collapse of the keyboard?
This happens when I move the mouse from the simulator

Comment: No idea, sorry... Probably worth asking a separate question regarding that issue providing you didn't find anything useful in the site search :)